# Passing filenames to python.subprocess across different platforms

Tags: python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I have a (cross-platform) script which invokes Excel/LibreOffice to open  a file. Under Linux I don't  have any problem, but with Windows there are problems when spaces are in the path of the file. This is a known issue, I've read quite some posts, but none seems to answer the specifics. Here is what I do:

`subprocess.run([self.settings.excel, path])`

The problem I end up with is the following: Excel complains that the file `Your%20Preferred%20Path%20With%20Spaces` cannot be found (obviously) although the parameter I give to subprocess isn't url-encoded like this.

So: who is garbaging my string ? Is it Excel, subprocess…?

I have found a workaround, using `os.startfile`, but it is not cross-platform. While having to execute different code according to the underlying platform may work as a patch, caring about so low-level details  is hardly pythonic.

Therefore: what should I do to have a cross-platform, standard code solving this issue (and avoiding big libs like `webbrowser` if at all possible)? How could I build `path` so that it is passed to Excel in the expected format?

Comment: The Python code you _show_ is fine, but the `path` is probably somehow populated incorrectly. Where does the value come from?

Comment: Windows is insane, so you might end up with a separate code path, something like `if sanity: subprocess.run([self.settings.excel, path], check=True) else: subprocess.run([self.settings.excel, path], shell=True, check=True)` or some such. Try with `start` and/or `cmd /c` or etc.

Comment: `subprocess` already works quite differently on Windows than on other platforms, so it very imperfectly abstracts the concept of a subprocess anyway. Under the hood, it passes a string to the Windows system call (`StartProcess` or some such?) and require `shell=True` when the commands require shell internals (`start`, `cd`, etc) whereas on Unix-like platforms it passes its arguments as a string to `/bin/sh` with `shell=True`, or else a list to `execve` with no shell facilities like wildcards, redirection, quoting, or, of course, shell internals like aliases, `cd`, shell variables etc.

Comment: @tripleee: Well, the string `path` is built in some method, but when I print it it appears unencoded. The modification takes place afterwards. The point is, I don't need shell commands, I'm only calling Excel. I already tried with `shell=True` and `check=True`, to no avail. I guess I'll have to resort to performing platform-specific calls. Thanks for your input anyway !